# How to convert a MySQL query to Laravel 5?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

i want to convert this mysql query to laravel. please advice

below is mysql code i tried

```
select 
 user_id,time_sheet_id,role_id,
 TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF( shift_end_time, shift_start_time)))), "%h:%i") AS diff
FROM 
 shifts
group by  
 time_sheet_id
```

this is my laravel code, but its giving syntax errors

```
 $findTotalhours =  DB::table('shifts')
                ->select(DB::raw('user_id, time_sheet_id,role_id TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF( shift_end_time, shift_start_time)))), "%h:%i") AS diff'))
                ->groupBy('time_sheet_id')
                ->get();
```

UPDATE

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF( shift_end_time, shift_start_time)))), "%h' at line 1 (SQL: select user_id, time_sheet_id,role_id TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF( shift_end_time, shift_start_time)))), "%h:%i") AS diff from `shifts` group by `time_sheet_id`)
```

Comment: Where are the syntax errors that it's giving? Paste your error output.

Comment: You have no comma between `role_id` and `TIME_FORMAT`.

Comment: @JRD : thanks, got it